# Multiprocessing Pool apply_async's workers and callback aren't called when executing in the inner scope

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, process-pool

Here is the code I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

CPU = 4

inp = pd.DataFrame({ 'col': ['a', 'b'] })

def test(dataframe):
    df = dataframe.copy()

    def worker(data):
        print('worker')

    def callback(data):
        print('callback')

    pool = mp.Pool(CPU)

    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        print((idx, row['col']))
        pool.apply_async(worker, args=[(idx, row['col'])], callback=callback)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    return df

test(inp)
```

It works as expected if I run in the upper scope (without enclosing in the `test` function), but after enclosing it in another function - they just are not called.

Here is output I receive with `test` function:

```
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
```

Without:

```
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
worker
worker
callback
callback
```

So the question is - **how can I make it work inside another function?**

Answer (score 1):

From [**`multiprocessing`**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiproc#module-multiprocessing) module documentation:

> *Safe importing of main module*
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a
>   starting a new process).

---

> **Note** Functionality within this package requires that the `__main__` module be importable by the children. This is covered in
>   [Programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiproc#multiprocessing-programming) however it is worth pointing out here.

The one of the proper ways would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

CPU = 4
inp = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['a', 'b']})

def worker(data):
    print(data)
    print('worker')

def callback(data):
    print('callback')

def test(dataframe):    
    df = dataframe.copy()   

    with mp.Pool(CPU) as pool:
        for idx, row in df.iterrows():
            result = pool.apply_async(worker, args=[(idx, row['col'])], callback=callback)
            result.wait()

    return df

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    test(inp)
```

The output:

```
(0, 'a')
worker
(1, 'b')
worker
callback
callback
```

Comment: well, what I wanted to do is to nest all helper functions under one parent, in this particular case under `test` function, is that possible? As I mentioned, If all functions live at the top level - code from my example works as well

Comment: @Shtirlits, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266803/multiprocessing-pool-not-working-in-nested-functions/46266853#46266853